# Reconstruction of a Pseudocode Observing Horizontal Spacing and Alignment

Tags: verbatim, algorithmic

In an attempt to reconstruct the following picture,
[image]

I have tried `verbatim` environment as below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}} 
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter} 
\makeatother
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
\begin{document}
    \begin{LTR}
        \begin{verbatim}
            TYPE ARRN      = ARRAY[1..N] OF INTEGER;
            ARR0N     = ARRAY[0..N] OF INTEGER;
            VERTPOINT = @VERTLIST;
            GRAPH     = ARRAY[1..N] OF
            RECORD
            DEGREE,COLOR:INTEGER;
            ADJLIST     :VERTPOINT;
            END;
            VERTLIST  = RECORD
            VERTEX:INTEGER;
            NEXT  :VERTPOINT
            END;
        \end{verbatim}
    \end{LTR}
\end{document}
```

However, the output is not what is shown in the original image, as is observable:[image]

I have tried to utilize `algorithmic` package, but I have not been able to get an output. I got the error "*Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ^^I\end{algorithmic}*", when I tried to run the below code:

```
\begin{algorithmic}
    \begin{LTR}
    TYPE ARRN      = ARRAY[1..N] OF INTEGER;
    ARR0N     = ARRAY[0..N] OF INTEGER;
    VERTPOINT = VERTLIST;
    GRAPH     = ARRAY[1..N] OF
    RECORD
    DEGREE,COLOR:INTEGER;
    ADJLIST     :VERTPOINT;
    END;
    VERTLIST  = RECORD
    VERTEX:INTEGER;
    NEXT  :VERTPOINT
    END;
    \end{LTR}
\end{algorithmic}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I should act in order to obtain an output resembling the intended image? Thanks.

**Edit**
As [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) pointed out, the site converts tabs into spaces. Therefore, I post the way the `verbatim` environment actually looks like in my TeX editor. The below picture's output is already shown in the second image.[image]

Comment: Please always provide full minimal examples not sniplets like this. Full minimal examplkes makes it a lot easier to test your issue. And what is `LTR` in this context?

Comment: @daleif I have modified the code so that a minimal working example is encompassed. Furthermore, `LTR` means left to right in the present context.

Comment: for verbatim use spaces not tabs, note that this site converts the tabs to spaces so if you look at your verbatim code as posted here the= are not lines up, fix that with spaces and it should look fine

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I posted a picture of my TeX editor in which the equal signs are aligned. It is that code which has produced the second image.

Comment: yes but you probably aligned them with tab (which does not work) rather than spaces, use the editor to untabify (or replace each tab with 4 spaces and fix any mis-alignment by hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spaces not tabs

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}} 
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter} 
\makeatother
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Times New Roman}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Tahoma}
\begin{document}
    \begin{LTR}
    \begin{verbatim}
       TYPE ARRN      = ARRAY[1..N] OF INTEGER;
            ARR0N     = ARRAY[0..N] OF INTEGER;
            VERTPOINT = @VERTLIST;
            GRAPH     = ARRAY[1..N] OF
                           RECORD
                              DEGREE,COLOR:INTEGER;
                              ADJLIST     :VERTPOINT;
                           END;
            VERTLIST  = RECORD
                           VERTEX:INTEGER;
                           NEXT  :VERTPOINT
                        END;
    \end{verbatim}
    \end{LTR}
\end{document}
```

If your editor does not offer a specific untabify function, just replace all tabs by 4 spaces and then correct the alignment by adding or removing spaces where needed.

Note that the indentation is not removed and appears in the output so you might (or might not) want to remove some of the spaces at the start of each line.